# Django 1.6 ORM Joins

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, orm

I'm trying to get all of the assets in a particular portfolio to display on a page.

I need to know:  A). How to get that portfolios primary key, B). How to write a join in code, and C). If I'm even going about this in the right way (would another CBV or FBV be more appropriate or is the function get_assets() fine?).

**Database setup:**

```
class Portfolios(models.Model):
    #code

class PortfoliosAssets(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolios)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Assets)

class Assets(models.Model):
    #code
```

**SQL I want to write with the ORM:**

```
SELECT A.ticker 
FROM assets A 
    INNER JOIN portfolios_assets PA ON PA.asset = A.id
WHERE PA.portfolio = --portfolio_pk
```

**Code:**

```
class ShowPortfolios(DetailView):
    model = Portfolios
    template_name = 'show_portfolios.html'

    def get_assets(self):
        #obviously not how to get the portfolios pk or columns from the ASSETS table.
        assets = PortfoliosAssets.objects.get(portfolio=portfolio_pk)
        for asset in assets:
           #run some query to get each asset's info but this seems obviously wrong.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between Portfolio and Asset is a many-to-many. You should define that explicitly, and remove the PortfolioAsset model completely (Django will create an equivalent m2m join table for you).

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    assets = models.ManyToManyField("Asset")
```

(Note the convention is to use singular names for models, not plurals.)

Once that's done, you don't need an extra method at all: you can simply access the asset from the portfolio via `portfolio.assets.all()`. Or, in the template:

```
{% for asset in portfolio.assets.all %}
    {{ asset.ticker }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In `portfolio.assets.all()`, that will get all of the assets that are present in one or more portfolios.  If I want to narrow it down to portfolio id 12 how would I specify the pk?  Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: No, `portfolio` is already the object passed from your DetailView, ie the one with the ID specified in the URL. So `portfolio.assets.all` is just the asserts related to that specific portfolio.